# DHCP server on ethernet port, keeping WiFi connection to Internet

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dhcp

*As an initial note*, I am using latest Mint, however I'd prefer a general (Ubuntu/Debian or even wider) solution, possibly for headless CLI-only too. Though I understand that may not be possible.

I have a device which needs to have the IP assigned externally (cannot configure internally as static). Everything works fine when I connect it to my router, and I can communicate `PC<-->router<-->device`. However, now I need to make that connection direct, i.e. `PC<-->device` (the device doesn't need Internet access, only to communicate with the PC). I would also like to keep being able to reach the Internet via WiFi on the PC.

What I've tried:

Set up a DHCP server with dnsmasq:

```
no-resolv
no-hosts
no-daemon
bogus-priv
 
interface=enp8s0
port=0
dhcp-range=192.168.88.10,static,infinite
listen-address=127.0.0.1
dhcp-host=<devicemacaddr>,device,192.168.88.67
dhcp-leasefile="storage.leases"
```

1. Worked fine, except that I had to manually add an interface in the `/etc/networking/` (because otherwise dnsmasq complained that it doesn't exist):

```
auto enp8s0
iface enp8s0 inet static
address 192.168.88.1
gateway 192.168.88.254
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

However, that must've messed some DNS settings, because since then I could not connect to some websites.

2. Deleted the interface file, went to Network manager > Wired and added new Profile with IPv4 and v6 set to Link-Local only.
   With this, I managed to connect to the device at least once, while maintaining my Internet connection. However, after a reboot it stopped working, and dnsmasq complains: `no address range available for DHCP request via enp8s0`.

Please, share your wisdom, o great wizards.

Comment: Mint is not supported on this Ubuntu support site. You can post your question to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP Range on `enp8s0` is `192.168.88.0/24`, your router has the IP `192.168.88.1`.

The internet is connectetd to the router?

Your interface definition does not need a gateway

```
auto enp8s0
iface enp8s0 inet static
address 192.168.88.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

is fine.
Please note This IP range must be unique, do not reuse it on any other interface of the router.
you dnsmaq.conf file should look like

```
no-resolv
no-hosts
no-daemon
bogus-priv
 
interface=enp8s0
port=0

dhcp-range=192.168.88.10,static,infinite # should be fine 
# listen-address=127.0.0.1 # relevant for the gui disable after troubleshooting
dhcp-host=<devicemacaddr>,device,192.168.88.67
dhcp-leasefile="storage.leases"
dhcp-option=3, 192.168.88.1 # default router for Device 
dhcp-option=6,<YOUR DNS SERVER>   # optional
```

connect to `http://<ROUTER-IP>:8080` for troubleshooting.

My best guess:

- You will be able to access the internet with your PC again
- You will be able to access the device with your PC
- The device itself may not be able to access the internet

have fun

Comment: Thank you, will check. Though I don't understand your question, `The internet is connected to the router?` You mean the physical router? Yes, it's connected to the Internet via ISP. And its local IP is 192.168.0.1.

Comment: Alright, I tweaked it just a bit, but generally it worked, with simultaneous access to the device and Internet